# Set Error message if customer is login from different group

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to restrict the login for particular group of customer from magento front side
So that i have put a check in `loginPostAction` method of customer `AccountController.php` file and redirect them on login page back.
But i could not able to set a error message like `You are not authorize person` on that page after redirection

Below is my code i made so far

```
 $session = $this->_getSession();

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);

        if($session->getCustomer()->getGroupId()!="4")
        {
                    $session->logout();

                    $message = 'You are not authorized person';
                    $session->addError($message);       

                    $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
                    return;
        }
      }
    }
```

So now if customer except 4 id group try to login, they will redirect back to login page but session message will not display.

I have tried this

```
          Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError($message);
```

and this also

```
          $message = $this->__('Got an error');
          Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($message);
```

Comment: Should work. What does your template look like? Was the block for messages removed on login page?

Comment: Hi @SimonH I have directly made a changes in customer module core files and i dont know where is the block for message display is exit?
could you plz give me the hints about where is that block exit to display message? thanks

Comment: Start in the page layout templat files in [yourtheme]/template/page/ (1column.phtml for example). Is there a line ` <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>`?